# GWT Google Charts - x value is in minutes - how to format x axis labels as hours?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a graph where the x value represents number of minutes within a duration.

I want to display *number of hours* as labels on the x axis, and when I hover the graph (showing the tooltip), I don't want to see some decimal value representing the hour (1.5), but rather a nicely formatted time (1h 30m) or maybe the number of minutes (90m).

I've been reading about annotation columns in the DataTable, but it seems to me that this is not yet supported by the GWT wrapper.

Still, I don't know if this is even possible to achieve, but if it is please let me know how!

Example code:

```
DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Time");
dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Value");
dataTable.addRow();
dataTable.setValue(0, 0, 0);
dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 100);
dataTable.addRow();
dataTable.setValue(1, 0, 45);
dataTable.setValue(1, 1, 1000);
dataTable.addRow();
dataTable.setValue(2, 0, 90);
dataTable.setValue(2, 1, 5000);

Options options = LineChart.createOptions();
AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
hAxisOptions.set("format", "#min");
options.setHAxisOptions(hAxisOptions);

options.setInterpolateNulls(true);
options.setCurveType("function");

container.clear();
container.add(new LineChart(dataTable, options));
```

[image: Example graph with comments]

Comment: I found some help in this SO question (the native method) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337000/combochart-with-annotation-text-in-gwt-google-visualization